# Is there some kind of USB antenna I can buy to be able to use Bitcoin even when there is no Internet?

Tags: network, synchronization, offline, offline-transactions, blockstream-satellite

Let's say they cut the Internet tomorrow. I will still have my private keys on my offline computer, but I won't be able to sync the blockchain (as won't anyone else) nor would i be able to make any transaction either.

But once I heard something about a satellite beaming down the blockchain at all times or something. And that was in like 2013. Did that ever go anywhere?

Is there some readily sold product which I can order which is like a little antenna which I attach via USB to my PC and which then can receive the blockchain and send coins via some kind of satellite or other form of radio communication in a decentralized manner?

Answer (score 1):

Blockstream have multiple satellite circling around the earth and broadcasting the blockchain or receiving and sending transaction without interruption.

https://blockstream.com/satellite/

They have their own kit to use the service:

https://store.blockstream.com/product/blockstream-satellite-basic-kit/

Comment: Note that the satellites aren't owned by Blockstream. They rent bandwidth on existing telecommunication satellites.